# In Android access mysql with java code

Tags: java, android, mysql

In Mysql table I have the database:-

```
mysql> use student
mysql> select * from ari;
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 22 | Sandy |
+----+-------+
```

I have installed jetty and mysql in my computer the ports are:--

```
http://localhost(172.0.0.1):8080/
http://localhost(172.0.0.1):3306/
```

This is my java code:--(**MainActivity.java**)

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student";
    private static final String user = "root";
    private static final String pass = "root";
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        testDB();
    } 

    public void testDB() {
        TextView tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            String result = "Database connection success\n";
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from ari");
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

            while(rs.next()) {
                            result += rsmd.getColumnName(1) + ": " + rs.getInt(1) + "\n";
                            result += rsmd.getColumnName(2) + ": " + rs.getString(2) + "\n";
                        }

            tv.setText(result);
               }
        catch(Exception e) {

                           e.printStackTrace();
                           tv.setText(e.toString());
        }   
    }
}
```

and the **activity_main.xml** is:--

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my project I also add **mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar**

But When I run it shows the error in my android device(phone):--

```
   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: 
 Could not create connection to database server
```

can anyone tell me where is the problem????????????????

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your app in your phone, obviously it needs to connect to your PC's ip address.
Not localhost.
And your PC and your phone needs to be in the same network.

E.g. jdbc:mysql://your-pc-ip-address:3306/student

Comment: Try connect to your PC's LAN address 192.168.1.XXX:3306

Answer (score 0):

You can check 2 points.

**1. DB running PC and Your phone are same network?**

**2. If 'root' user has not '%' permissions, you should add this permissions.**

```
create user 'root'@'@' identified by 'root';
```

Comment: I am using wifi in my mobile,So this is not the same network.I understand the problem..
But when I use emulator to run this..same error is occuring..

Comment: As just easy ways, Smartphone and Your PC connected same wi-fi.

Comment: But, I am not recommendate this way. So add permission to 'root' user.

Comment: create user 'root'@'@' identified by 'root';
ERROR 1105 (HY000): Malformed hostname (illegal symbol: '@')

Comment: "create user 'root'@'@' identified by 'root';"  are you sure that this command is correct?

Comment: Sure, I did this command in mysql. so, I'm success add this permission. I want to show capture, but I can't upload image. because now i'm in company. sorry...

Comment: If you were adding this permission, you can show 'root' user who adding host '%'. through this command. "select user, host from user where user='root'"

Comment: 'root' is change your hostname!!